# Run project ionic failed command ionic cordova run android

Tags: android, cordova

i get this error when running command ionic cordova run android

ANDROID_HOME=C:\androidsdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE:
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 57.141 secs
Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\doc\blank\platforms\android\build.gradle' line: 20
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

  > java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

i used android studio 3.2.1 and build tool 25.0.3
i need help please

Comment: Have you tried `cordova clean` command? also try `ionic platform remove android` and then `ionic platform add android`

Comment: yes @David after run cordova clean command i still have a same error

Comment: @David i used android studio 3.2.1 and build tool 25.0.3